# org-mode capture template prompt directly to agenda without opening file

Tags: org-capture

I defined a template like so

```
 ("g" "Godo"
          entry
          (file+headline "~/mega/org/gcal.org" "Tasks")
          "* TODO %^{description}%?\n %T %i\n %a")))
```

and when pressing C-c c g I am prompted for a descpription. But after putting it in and hitting return, I am still taken to the file gcal. how can I achieve that the text I enter in the minibuffer is just combined with the current date and put into the gcal file without putting me in the capture template buffer?

Comment: Does adding the property `:immediate-finish` help any?:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html  See also:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3um5ic/bypass_orgcapture_editing_step_with_orgprotocol/?st=k2nrtym4&sh=61ea30bc

Comment: it helps. just what I wanted. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the property `:immediate-finish` will have the desired effect:

https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html

`:immediate-finish`:  "*When set, do not offer to edit the information, just file it away immediately. This makes sense if the template only needs information that can be added automatically.*"